# Check if object in array of protocol is of type subclass

Tags: swift

I have a Protocol

```
protocol ActionProtocol {
    func revert(_ myObject: MyObject)
}
```

and a parent class

```
class MyAction<T>: ActionProtocol {
    func revert(_ myObject: MyObject)
}
```

and multiple child classes

```
class ChildAction1: MyAction<MyObject> {
    override func revert(_ myObject: MyObject) {
        // do something
    }
}

class ChildAction2: MyAction<MyObject> {
    override func revert(_ myObject: MyObject) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

In my code depending on some conditions I add some of these to an array.

```
var actions: [ActionProtocol] = []
actions.append(ChildAction1())
actions.append(ChildAction2())
// and so on
```

I now want to know which of these Subclasses I have when calling `actions.last` for example. I have tried `type(of: actions.last)` and `actions.last.dynamicType` and `actions.last is ChildAction1` but all of them do not work. It always says it's of type ActionProtocol.

How can I check if the actual type of the object is `ChildAction1`?

Comment: IMO You design is flawed. This is not how you should use protocols. If you really want to have a collection of objects that conform to a Protocol you shouldn't need to know the type of the object that conforms to it. All you should need is access to the properties/methods required by your protocol.

Comment: The only way to know if your collection element is of a certain type is conditionally trying to cast to your type `yourElement as? ChildAction1` but again it doesn't make any sense IMO

Comment: Okay but I have like 6 kind of differenct actions that all have a `revert`. And I have an array that tracks all the actions, that's why I have created the protocol so that I can call `revert` on the actions in the array. I also could add a method that tells me if the action in the list if of one of the types I am looking for.

Comment: In this case add a property to your protocol with an Enumeration

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. `actions.last is ChildAction2` returns true for your above example. I agree with Leo that this might indicate a design flaw (though it might also be fine), but it's fully supported and legal, and seems to work. Can you show exactly what you mean by "does not work?"

Comment: Yes my mistake I just realized that it worked I have selected the wrong ChildAction and wondered why it didn't work. But thank you for your ideads